# Use JetBrains Toolbox to get Early Access versions

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-toolbox

I am using the [*Jetbrains Toolbox*](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) tool to auto-install updates to [IntelliJ IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA). This works well for regular releases.

But how do I use this tool to obtain an [Early Access](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/#section=mac) pre-release?

I see a hexagon-shape icon that displays a menu. But the menu items there say nothing about skipping ahead to a pre-release. The items there are only `Settings`, `Roll back to…`, and `Uninstall`. I checked the `Settings` display, but no options there to enroll in the Early Access program.

[image: Screenshot of Jetbrains Toolbox app]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Redundant product listing

Scroll down to the item at the bottom that redundantly lists your licensed product, *IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate*.

Click the *Install Again* pop-up menu. Choose the pre-release version you want.

[image: screenshot of Jetbrains Toolbox list of apps, scrolled to the bottom.]

After download completes, you will see another product listing at the top of the app list.

[image: screenshot of Jetbrains Toolbox app after installing a pre-release version now listed at the top]